# How to query with string variable in rails 3.2.12?

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We would like to store both rails query string and table name in db and retrieve them for execution at run time. Here is the scenario:

Retrieve active `customer` records from `customers` table. Let's say we have 2 variable defined as:

```
table_name = 'Customer'
query_string = ':active => true'
```

In rails, the query could be:

```
records = Customer.where(:active => true)
```

Now with table name and query string stored in variables table_name and query_string, is it possible to assemble a query string with 2 variables like:

```
 records = table_name.where(query_string) ?
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, but it's not generally recommended to evaluate a string as a hash.  Also, `table_name` is an unfortunate name for the variable, because you actually are storing the class name (table would be 'customers').  In any event, what you are missing is the eval of these strings:

```
records = class_name.constantize.where(instance_eval(query_string))
```

Note that running `instance_eval` on a user-inputted string can be disasterous for security and the well-being of your application.  Use with care, and stick to building an actual hash.

Comment: is class_name = 'Customer' in your answer? The string would be pulled from readonly data table. If the data table is generally secure, is there other risk with this kind of coding practice?

Comment: @user938363: Yes, `class_name = 'Customer'`.  How is this query data getting into the data table?  And what are you trying to accomplish that you can't already do with scopes and class methods?  It just seems a sloppy and difficult-to-maintain approach to something that has more elegant and predictable solutions.

Comment: We are designing a access control and would like to describe the access and save it into a table. The data is saved in data onboarding process and would give us a flexibility to accommodate future changes by just changing onboarding data. Our purpose is to avoid code change with data driven.

Comment: @user938363: look into [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), it will probably do what you need without resorting to this approach.  You can use role entries (data driven) to determine which permissions should apply.

Comment: There is an error when executing the code: SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting $end
:active=>true
         ^
        from (irb):8:in `instance_eval'

Comment: We need much fine-grained access control based on role and group. It seems hard to fit into any current product. That's why we end up designing our own.

Comment: Try surrounding the `query_string` argument with parens - updated.

Comment: Same error. The class_name.constantize works. However somehow true after => in where causes error.

Comment: @user938363: I think it's because nothing indicates to `instance_eval` that this should be parsed as a hash.  Try this instead `instance_eval("{#{query_string}}")`.  Or simply add the brackets in your string.

Comment: instance_eval("{#{query_string}}") works. Instead of evaled, the query_string just needs to be passed into the where and the {} serves the purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `instance_eval` is: `Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (obj).`

Another way to eval a query string is to include `where` in the string, like:

```
table_name = 'Customer'
query_string = 'where(:active => true)'
```

Then the record could be retrieved by:

```
records = table_name.constantize.instance_eval(query_string)
```

By putting `where` into the string, we can use the full power of instance_eval instead of just returning the source code to `where` as in the question above.